# DROP TABLE customer_grid_flat hangs - deadlock during customer grid indexing?

Tags: magento2.2, reindex, indexing, deadlock

We have had an issue with Magento 2.2.5 on an AWS RDS instance (MySQL 5.7):
Every then and when, essential Magento Admin functionality is blocked. It is possible to login, but order and customer list can not be shown - the requests just time out.

A look at the running processes in the database shows a combination of DROP TABLE, DESCRIBE, and sometimes even INSERT requests for the table `customer_grid_flat` - all at the same time.

We have tried to kill all these statements, but the `DROP TABLE` statement won't disappear, and the `DESCRIBE` statements would reappear - most presumably, because indexes are being re-run on a repeating basis.

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-------+----------+------------------+--------------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Id    | User     | Host             | db                 | Command | Time | State                           | Info                                      |
+-------+----------+------------------+--------------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|     2 | rdsadmin | localhost:57128  | mysql              | Sleep   |    7 |                                 | NULL                                      |
| 87187 | root     | 10.0.0.111:56026 | magento            | Killed  | 3449 | checking permissions            | DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer_grid_flat` |
| 88334 | root     | 10.0.0.112:49560 | magento            | Query   |    0 | starting                        | show processlist                          |
| 88862 | root     | 10.0.0.112:50962 | magento            | Sleep   |  752 |                                 | NULL                                      |
| 88998 | root     | 10.0.0.11:52606  | information_schema | Query   |  939 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `COLUMNS`            |
| 89197 | root     | 10.0.0.112:41564 | magento            | Query   | 1306 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DESCRIBE `customer_grid_flat`             |
| 89304 | root     | 10.0.0.112:41772 | magento            | Query   | 1201 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DESCRIBE `customer_grid_flat`             |
| 89305 | root     | 10.0.0.112:41776 | magento            | Query   | 1197 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DESCRIBE `customer_grid_flat`             |
| 89310 | root     | 10.0.0.112:41798 | magento            | Query   | 1189 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DESCRIBE `customer_grid_flat`             |
| 89313 | root     | 10.0.0.112:41802 | magento            | Query   | 1186 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DESCRIBE `customer_grid_flat`             |
| 89374 | root     | 10.0.0.112:41998 | magento            | Query   | 1074 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DESCRIBE `customer_grid_flat`             |
| 89554 | root     | 10.0.0.11:52642  | information_schema | Query   |  512 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `COLUMNS`            |
| 89577 | root     | 10.0.0.112:42406 | magento            | Query   |  857 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DESCRIBE `customer_grid_flat`             |
| 89591 | root     | 10.0.0.112:42438 | magento            | Query   |  831 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DESCRIBE `customer_grid_flat`             |
| 89930 | root     | 10.0.0.11:52674  | information_schema | Sleep   |   14 |                                 | NULL                                      |
| 89931 | root     | 10.0.0.11:52676  | NULL               | Sleep   |   11 |                                 | NULL                                      |
| 90003 | root     | 10.0.0.112:43802 | magento            | Query   |  213 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DESCRIBE `customer_grid_flat`             |
| 90025 | root     | 10.0.0.112:43910 | magento            | Query   |  197 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DESCRIBE `customer_grid_flat`             |
+-------+----------+------------------+--------------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

We found some information here on StackExchange (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883936/process-that-was-killed-still-on-my-processlist and some others), - but basically, it says, we have to wait until the process is killed, or to restart the RDS instance. Waiting ... well, we've tried that, but more than 30 minutes waiting time (we are still waiting) is not a good solution, if essential functionality of the system is not usable during that time.
This is not a production system, but we want to avoid restarts of the database for obvious reasons. We want to find a way to solve this issue without restarting the database.

Any hints?

Comment: Have you found a solution to the problem?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147260)